# In Observable Plot, how to sort/order the stack from a bin() transform?

Tags: plot, data-visualization, observablehq

I'm working on a stacked bar chart in Observable's new [Plot](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/plot) library.  It's not too bad coming from Vega and D3, but I cannot find or figure how to order the resulting stacked bars from the [Plot.binX()](https://github.com/observablehq/plot#bin) I'm using.

My actual mark looks something like this today:

```js
Plot.rectY(hourlyUsageData, Plot.binX({
      y: "sum", 
      title: bin => bin[0].Name
    }, {
      x: d => d3.timeHour.count(d3.timeDay(d.DateTime), d.DateTime),
      y: d => d.kWh,
      thresholds: 24,
      fill: "Name",
      //order: "sum",
      //reverse: true
    }))
```

`Plot.binX()` does just fine, resulting in a chart in which the stack is ordered according to the input ordering.

I'd like the stack to be ordered based on a sum, and in fact if I add the [Plot.stack](https://github.com/observablehq/plot/blob/main/README.md#stack) option for `order` (see commented line above), I can order by sum:

[image: Wrongly-ordered stacked bar]

Close!  Now I just need to reverse the order.  I hypothesize that, since I can use the `order` option, perhaps I can also use the `reverse` option (see commented line above).  *That doesn't seem to work*.

My second hypothesis is that, since these transforms are supposed to be "composable", that I should be able to combine my `binX` with a `stackY`, but I cannot find an example of such a composition.  I've tried `Plot.stackY(Plot.binX({...}, { ... order:"sum", reverse:true })`, and similar variations, but *they don't seem to work* either.

In summary, I'd love to know how to control the order of the stacks in my stacked bar chart while also using binX.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you. It seems that there is a bug and the {order} option is consumed for nothing by the bin transform. We'll try to fix this. In the meantime you can add it "outside" the bin transform like so:

```
Plot.rectY(data,
  Plot.stackY({
    ...Plot.binX(
      { y: "count" },
      { x: "body_mass", fill: "species", order: "sum" }
    ),
    reverse: true
  })
).plot()
```

Pull-request to solve this issue: https://github.com/observablehq/plot/pull/439

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you!  I've been treating the construction of these Plot objects as a DSL, but seeing how to compose two transforms together with a spread helps my mental model at least.